# Internationalization and i18n - are separate tags really needed?

Tags: discussion, tags

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) "i18n" is nothing but abbreviation of "internationalization". However, on this site [i18n](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/i18n) is tag about a module, and [internationalization](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internationalization) is without description altogether.

I guess best bet would be to make them synonyms and let them mean both process and standard module to perform that process. even if someone will not want to use that exact module, he would have to deal with specifying why not to use it.

Comment: Since you have >2500 reputation, have you suggested it on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/i18n/synonyms ?

Comment: @int_ua Nope, I wasn't even near 1k when I posted this, as far as I remember ;)